# C#: DataGridView's content does not appear in hard print copy

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, printing, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` and by clicking print button it shows print preview and then by clicking on print button it supposed to print the print preview content.

The problem is my `DataGridView` content is displayed in print preview but when I save it as XPS document. It doesn't show `DataGridView` content. although header and footer is there. But only `DataGridView` data is not printing.

This is the code for printing rows:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(list[i].Sr.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 12), Brushes.Black, new Point(35, yposition));
e.Graphics.DrawString(list[i].Name.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 12), Brushes.Black, new Point(80, yposition));
e.Graphics.DrawString(list[i].Packing.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 12), Brushes.Black, new Point(355, yposition));
e.Graphics.DrawString(list[i].Quantity.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 12), Brushes.Black, new Point(495, yposition));
e.Graphics.DrawString(list[i].Price.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 12), Brushes.Black, new Point(560, yposition));
e.Graphics.DrawString(list[i].TotalAmount.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 12), Brushes.Black, new Point(680, yposition));
```

I am using *Visual Studio 2013*.

Comment: You probably are not resetting the row indexer after you preview, **but** that code looks like it is printing a List or Array not a DGV, and do you really need a **new** font for each item?

Comment: i am using a list  to get data grid view values

Comment: Please don't use "C#" etc. in your topic titles. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Can you show the saving code?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably doing too much work here. You can draw your entire `DataGridView` to a `Graphics` object using the following simple code:

```
using(Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(800, 600))
{
  YourDataGridView.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, 800, 600);
  e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(bmp, 0, 0);
}
```

This should work for both PrintPreview and Print.

Comment: I would expect this to look terrible.